# Difference between CallTo/To and CallFrom/From in Twilio

Tags: twilio

When I make an outgoing call using Twilio API & TwiML App Twilio makes request to my server with following params:

```
  'AccountSid' => '...',
  'ApplicationSid' => '...',
  'Caller' => 'client:2',
  'CallStatus' => 'ringing',
  'callFrom' => 'some_phone_number',
  'Called' => '',
  'To' => '',
  'callTo' => 'some_phone_numeber',
  'CallSid' => '...',
  'From' => 'client:2',
  'Direction' => 'inbound',
  'ApiVersion' => '2010-04-01',
```

what's the difference between CallTo (which equals the actual phone number I'm calling to) and To (which is empty for some reason) ? Same for From and CallFrom. I couldn't find any info in the docs about callTo/callFrom. Plus, why To is empty?

**Update**

Some additional info. I make a call from twilio number to real Russian phone number. I actually hangup the call. There is no forwarding/redirecting. The Twiml app for outgoing calls is:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="{{ $callFrom }}"
          record="record-from-ringing"
          action="{{ $action }}">
        <Number>{{ $callTo }}</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

CallFrom and CallTo equals those which are passed with the request. So the data I mentioned above is what Twilio passes with the request, and then Twilio gets the TwiML instructions.

What I do not understand if that what's the difference between to/from? Are from/to fields used when dealing with client names, like for internal conversation or kind of...?

And another question is: when the call is finished and the action url called, twilio passes DialCallStatus and CallStatus, what's the difference there? I need to store call status so that I know if the client was busy and didn't answer, but DialCallStatus has different value from CallStatus.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Twilio developer evangelist here. Can you please give me more information about this call? Are you just plainly calling a Twilio number, and this is the request you get to your server? Is there any redirecting going on?

Comment: Oh, Hi Marcos. I've added update to my initial message. Thanks!